# Finding modified date and time of file from recovered disk image

Tags: data-recovery, forensics

Some jpeg files have been recovered from an image file of a floppy disk.

Is there a way to get the modified, created and last accessed date and times of those files recovered, i.e. the time and date on the floppy disk not the PC it was recovered on?

I have tried commands like find and stat, but they give the times of when the files were retrieved on my own machine.

Comment: No: you have to extract those times from the floppy image.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what method you're using to recover this data but in general this data is lost as a by product of how Unix filesystems delete files.

#### Recovery method #1 - Photorec

When you use this software to recover deleted files, the original file's date/time meta information is gone. This occurred when the file was originally deleted.

*excerpt from [photorec webpage](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)*

> When a file is deleted, the meta-information about this file (file name, date/time, size, location of the first data block/cluster, etc.) is lost; for example, in an ext3/ext4 file system, the names of deleted files are still present, but the location of the first data block is removed. This means the data is still present on the file system, but only until some or all of it is overwritten by new file data.

#### Recovery method #2 - pulling files from .img image

If on the other hand you're mounting existing image files of floppies, then you should be able to extract the original meta information for each file without any issues. You just have to use either `rsync -a` or `cp -p` to preserve this information when extracting these files from the `.img` file.

#### Example

Here I have the following `.img` file of a floppy.

```
$ ls -l /home/saml/tst/96360/floppy.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 saml saml 1474560 Dec 21 16:23 /home/saml/tst/96360/floppy.img
```

If I mount it like this:

```
$ sudo mount /home/saml/tst/96360/floppy.img /mnt/
```

It contains the following files:

```
$ ll
total 23
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  1024 Dec 28  2006 boot
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  9363 Aug 21  2007 kernel
drwx------. 2 root root 12288 Dec 28  2006 lost+found
```

I can start copying files from this `.img` file like so:

```
$ cp -p /mnt/kernel /tmp/.
$ ls -l /tmp/kernel 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 saml saml 9363 Aug 21  2007 /tmp/kernel
```

As you can see the original meta information was preserved just fine.

Comment: I recovered the files with foremost and autopsy. the disk image was a raw file

Comment: @sunrise3333 - so the raw file is a .img file then, correct? If you have the `.img` file you can use the command `file blah.img` to find out the type of file.

Comment: yes its a DOS floppy 1440k, x86 hard disk boot sector, but what can I do with tht info? When I examine the image in hex editor there is the headers of a spanned archive (PK) but im unable to retrieve the zip files there is like 4 one after the other

Comment: You probably just need to help the `mount` command out by specifying msdos. Ex: `mount -t msdos /path/to/floppy.img /mnt`.

Comment: it returns 'it is not a block device'

Comment: @sunrise3333 - Can you include the exact msg. from the file command? It would appear to not be a dos floppy then.

Comment: mount: /home/cemal/Desktop/10thenron/10thenron is not a block device (maybe try `-o loop'?)

Comment: @sunrise3333 - sure try it. I've not had to use it in this situation, usually with `.iso` files but you could try it.

Comment: it returns:
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so

im unix newbie no clue about this

Comment: @sunrise3333 - run the command `dmesg` after trying to do the `mount` command. The last few lines should tell you more info. Is it possible to share this `.img` file? Might be easier for me to try mounting it for you. LMK.

Comment: the thing is i have mounted it, and got back some files, but there are also some hidden files inside

Comment: @sunrise3333 - what command was able to mount it?

Comment: $ sudo mount /home/saml/tst/96360/floppy.img /mnt/